# SSRS show Group even when NULL

Tags: sql, reporting-services, group-by, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I would like to show on my SSRS report the following case types even if they have null values.

`Project Finance`,`Whole of Market`,`CustomBuild`

```
    SELECT Count(ct.CaseTypeDesc)AS Done, ct.CaseTypeDesc,ap.StatusDesc As [Mortgage Status],SUM(pm.ProcFeeExp + pm.ArrangementFee) As Total ,u.Fullname as Advisor
FROM dbo.tbl_Profile AS p
INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_Profile_Mortgage AS pm
ON p.ID = pm.FK_ProfileID
INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_AppStatus AS ap
ON pm.MortgageStatus = ap.StatusID
INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_CaseTypes AS ct
ON p.CasetypeID = ct.CaseTypeID
LEFT JOIN dbo.tbl_User AS u
ON p.Advisor = u.UserID
WHERE pm.MortgageStatus = 7
AND ct.CaseTypeDesc  IN ('Project Finance','Whole of Market','CustomBuild')
AND p.Advisor IN (266,104,172,145,177,253,286,261,289,138)
AND  (
            pm.DatePassed       BETWEEN @Start AND @End
        OR  pm.DateCompleted        BETWEEN @Start AND @End
        OR  pm.DateOffered      BETWEEN @Start AND @End
        )
GRoup By u.Fullname,ct.CaseTypeDesc,ap.StatusDesc
```

When i run this report there might be no count for `Whole of Market`
However i still want my report to group by `Whole of Market` and show `0`.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is your query returning null for `Whole of Market`? I mean your query returns `Project Finance` and `CustomBuild` for `CaseTypeDesc` column but it doesn't return `Whole of Market`, right?

Comment: Hi It will return all 3 casetypes Project Finance,Whole of Market,CustomBuild if it has a count on it.So for instance it will show custombuild 12, Whole of market 6.

Comment: What i would like it to say is custombuild 12, Whole of market 6, Project Finance 0

Comment: In your case Project Finance is not returned since there is no count on it?

Comment: So even if there isn't a count on anyone of the 3 casetypes i still want it to show the 3 casetypes Project Finance 0 ,Whole of Market 0 ,CustomBuild 0

Answer (score 0):

If you use `GROUP BY` clause it will not distinct the `NULL` values. I think an easy solution is use `UNION ALL` operator to add rows for different `CaseTypeDesc` instead.

Something like this:

```
select count(CaseTypeDesc) ...
from ...
where CaseTypeDesc = 'Project Finance'
UNION ALL
select count(CaseTypeDesc)...
from ...
where CaseTypeDesc = 'Whole of Market'
UNION ALL
select count(CaseTypeDesc)...
from ...
where CaseTypeDesc = 'CustomBuild'
```

It will give you the Whole of Market count to zero even if it doesn't appear in your query.

This should be your query.

```
SELECT Count(ct.CaseTypeDesc)AS Done, 'Project Finance' CaseTypeDesc,ap.StatusDesc As [Mortgage Status],
SUM(pm.ProcFeeExp + pm.ArrangementFee) As Total ,u.Fullname as Advisor
FROM dbo.tbl_Profile AS p
INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_Profile_Mortgage AS pm
ON p.ID = pm.FK_ProfileID
INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_AppStatus AS ap
ON pm.MortgageStatus = ap.StatusID
INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_CaseTypes AS ct
ON p.CasetypeID = ct.CaseTypeID
LEFT JOIN dbo.tbl_User AS u
ON p.Advisor = u.UserID
WHERE pm.MortgageStatus = 7
AND ct.CaseTypeDesc  = 'Project Finance'
AND p.Advisor IN (266,104,172,145,177,253,286,261,289,138)
AND  (
            pm.DatePassed       BETWEEN @Start AND @End
        OR  pm.DateCompleted        BETWEEN @Start AND @End
        OR  pm.DateOffered      BETWEEN @Start AND @End
        )
UNION ALL
SELECT Count(ct.CaseTypeDesc)AS Done, 'Whole of Market' as CaseTypeDesc,ap.StatusDesc As [Mortgage Status],
SUM(pm.ProcFeeExp + pm.ArrangementFee) As Total ,u.Fullname as Advisor
FROM dbo.tbl_Profile AS p
INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_Profile_Mortgage AS pm
ON p.ID = pm.FK_ProfileID
INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_AppStatus AS ap
ON pm.MortgageStatus = ap.StatusID
INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_CaseTypes AS ct
ON p.CasetypeID = ct.CaseTypeID
LEFT JOIN dbo.tbl_User AS u
ON p.Advisor = u.UserID
WHERE pm.MortgageStatus = 7
AND ct.CaseTypeDesc  = 'Whole of Market'
AND p.Advisor IN (266,104,172,145,177,253,286,261,289,138)
AND  (
            pm.DatePassed       BETWEEN @Start AND @End
        OR  pm.DateCompleted        BETWEEN @Start AND @End
        OR  pm.DateOffered      BETWEEN @Start AND @End
        )
UNION ALL
SELECT Count(ct.CaseTypeDesc)AS Done, 'CustomBuild' as CaseTypeDesc,ap.StatusDesc As [Mortgage Status],
SUM(pm.ProcFeeExp + pm.ArrangementFee) As Total ,u.Fullname as Advisor
FROM dbo.tbl_Profile AS p
INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_Profile_Mortgage AS pm
ON p.ID = pm.FK_ProfileID
INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_AppStatus AS ap
ON pm.MortgageStatus = ap.StatusID
INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_CaseTypes AS ct
ON p.CasetypeID = ct.CaseTypeID
LEFT JOIN dbo.tbl_User AS u
ON p.Advisor = u.UserID
WHERE pm.MortgageStatus = 7
AND ct.CaseTypeDesc  = 'CustomBuild'
AND p.Advisor IN (266,104,172,145,177,253,286,261,289,138)
AND  (
            pm.DatePassed       BETWEEN @Start AND @End
        OR  pm.DateCompleted        BETWEEN @Start AND @End
        OR  pm.DateOffered      BETWEEN @Start AND @End
        )
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Hi alejandro Its still missing out the casetypes that dont have a count on it.

Comment: What are you getting when running the query?

Comment: The exact same as when i run it with all the casetypes with the union all. It brings back Project finance and Whole of market but nothing for CustomBuild. Was hoping it would show CustomBuild as 0 but showing nothing

Comment: Could you share a sample data of your tables specifically for `CustomBuilds`?